# operations on ideals in a subring of number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra

For three ideals $I, J$ and $K$ of a subring $R$ in a number field $L$,
does this equality hold in general?

$(I+J) \cap K = (I \cap K) + (J \cap K)$

I have no counterexample yet but I couldn't prove this.

Does this hold if $R$ is a finite local ring over $\mathbb{Z}_p$? 
(In other words, $R$ is a local ring and $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module of finite rank.)

Comment: The lattice of ideals in a Dedekind domain is distributive, being isomorphic to a direct sum of the linearly ordered lattices $(\mathbb N,\le)$ (with one summand for each prime). This shows the identity holds at least for $R=\mathcal O_K$.

Comment: BTW, you might want to disambiguate $K$ from $K$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: distributivity of the lattice of ideals for a commutative (noetherian) ring with no zero divisors is equivalent to the ring being Pr\"ufer (Dedekind). [See the references in wikipedia]. So, for a counter-example which is not even integrally closed, in a quadratic extension of the rational numbers take the "naive integers": integer linear combinations of 1 and a square root of an integer in cases where to obtain the integral closure one needs linear combinations with half-integer coefficients (for example, cubic roots of 1).

For the second question, I still have to check Bourbaki's exercises for potential counter-examples. What is sure is that (1) for a noetherian local commutative ring being uniserial is the same as having distributive lattice of ideals, hence it is also equivalent to being a discrete valuation domains or artinian uniserial i.e. proper homomorphic image of a discrete valuation domain (see the chapters by Tuganbaev in the Handbook of algebra for much more general results); (2)  finitely generated modules over a noetherian uniserial ring (or more generally finitely presented modules over a serial ring) are (finite) direct sum of uniserial (finitely presented) submodules (Warfield's theorem). But when one applies this to a ring $R$ as module over a discrete valuation domain one does not obtain that $R$ is serial as module over itself (only over the valuation domain).

I suspect that even finite rings $R$ whose additive group is a $p$-group could give counterexamples (as modules over the integers modulo $p^n$, and then a Hensel lemma technology should give a example over the $p$-adic integers), Or one could try the localizations (and then completions) of the number field examples above.

Comment: To make a local counterexample, let $A$ be an unramified extension of $\mathbf{Z}_p$ with degree $n > 1$ and $R \subset A$ the subring of elements reducing into $\mathbf{F}_p$ in the residue field $A/pA$.  Then $R$ has maximal ideal $pA$ that is *not* $pR$, and $pA/p^2A$ as an $R$-module is "just" an $\mathbf{F}_p$-vector space of dimension $n$. Hence, one can pick $I, J, K \subset pA \subset R$ corresponding to subspaces $V,V',W$ of $\mathbf{F}_p^n$ such that $(V+V')\cap W$ strictly contains $(V\cap W) + (V'\cap W)$. Three distinct lines through 0 in a plane does the job when $n=2$.

Comment: The above comment with $n=2$ readily adapts to the global number field setting, using orders with $p$-power index in a quadratic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ unramified at $p$.

Comment: In the example, are I,J, and K ideals?